# I need to pull digit places (like tenths place, hundredths place, etc...)

Tags: java

I need to pull out a specific number place, like tenths place, out of numbers that the client puts in. For example, they put in the number 156 and if I need the tenths place, they pull out the 5. Or if they need the hundredths place it will pull out 1.

This is my first Java programming class so we haven't gone over the advanced stuff yet, but here is what I have so far:

```
    /**
 * @author Eddie Maiale
 * @version October 1st, 2015
 */
public class LcdDigit {
    //Digit display field
    private int digitValue;

    public LcdDigit() {
        digitValue = 0;
    }

    public LcdDigit (int newDigitValue, int place) {
        if (newDigitValue >  0) {
            digitValue = newDigitValue;
        }

        if (place < 10) {
            digitValue = digitValue % 10;
        } else if (place < 100) {
            digitValue = digitValue % 100;
        } else {
            digitValue = digitValue % 1000;
        }

    }

    public int getDigitValue() {
        return digitValue;
    }

    public void setDigitValue (int newDigitValue, double place) {
        if (newDigitValue > 0) {
            digitValue = newDigitValue;
        }

        if (place < 10) {
            digitValue = digitValue % 10;
        } else if (place < 100) {
            digitValue = digitValue % 100;
        } else {
            digitValue = digitValue % 1000;
        }
    }

    public String returnString() {
        return "" + digitValue;
    }
}
```

This is what the client code is:

```
class LcdDigitDriver {


 /** The main method where the program starts. */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        LcdDigit noArgs = new LcdDigit();
        LcdDigit onesPlace = new LcdDigit(456, 1);
        LcdDigit tensPlace = new LcdDigit(456, 10);
        LcdDigit hundredsPlace = new LcdDigit(456, 100);
        System.out.println(noArgs.getDigitValue());
        System.out.println(onesPlace.getDigitValue());
        System.out.println(tensPlace.getDigitValue());
        System.out.println(hundredsPlace.getDigitValue());
        System.out.println(hundredsPlace.returnString());
        hundredsPlace.setDigitValue(892, 100);
        System.out.println(hundredsPlace.getDigitValue());
    }
}
```

And the output needs to look like this:

```
0
6
5
4
4
8
```

Edit: Current output is like this:

```
0
6 
56 
456 
456 
892
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your constructor to this:

```
public LcdDigit (int newDigitValue, int place) {
    if (newDigitValue >  0) {
        digitValue = newDigitValue;
    }

    if (place == 1) {
        digitValue = digitValue % 10;
    } else if (place == 10) {
        digitValue = (digitValue / 10) % 10;
    } else {
        digitValue = (digitValue / 100) % 10;
    }

}
```

You will also have to change your `setDigitValue` method to something similar.

This works by moving the digit that you are looking for to the one's place, which is then easily found by using the modulus operator. For example, if your digit value is `230` and you're trying to find the ten's place you would first divide by `10`. The resulting value is `23`. `23 % 10` equals `3`, which is the digit in the ten's place of the original value.

Comment: It worked like a CHARM!!! Could you explain this to me? I understand the operand part (% 10) but why also the division? 

Thanks though!

Comment: @EddieMaiale Sure.  I added an explanation to my answer.  Hopefully it is helpful. There are very likely better ways of doing this.  I encourage you to experiment!

Comment: This can be simplified to "digitValue = (digitValue / place) % 10" to get any positive "place"

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having some sort of for loop that looks at each place value. Id say that you can use the .length to find how many numbers are in string/number. So, 156, there are 3. From there, you could decrement from the index of 2 to 0. I say 2 because in java, indexes start from 0 and go up from there. In this case, 0 index is 1, 1 index is 5, and 2 index is 6. We know that the first value is our "ones" and from there you can have an array which takes in all those values. Hence, you'd have each ones value and so on. From there you can do whatever you need with those numbers.

Comment: We have not covered loops yet and therefore I can't use them unfortunately :(

Comment: Well in your code youre using a while loop, hence my thought you know loops.

Answer (score 0):

You can do by checking the multiplier (tenth, hundreds, etc) and using this method :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // will show the 'thousands' in 1234
    System.out.println(getTheNthDigitFromNumber(1234,1000));

    // will show the 'hundreds' in 235464
    System.out.println(getTheNthDigitFromNumber(235464,100));
}

public static char getTheNthDigitFromNumber(int number,int multiplier){
    int thePosition=0;
    while(multiplier > 0){
        thePosition++;
        multiplier /= 10;

    }
    // converting to string and finding the char from the end
    String theNumber=String.valueOf(number);
    return theNumber.charAt(theNumber.length() - thePosition);
}
```